meaning of "something" in this context
https://vivfortoday.com/relationships/dear-mom/
(I wish you weren’t a stranger.
Mark remembers you. He was eight when you passed away. Sometimes I envy the fact that he has his memory to go on. Other times, though, I think I got off lucky. Especially when it comes to Mimi. She married dad a couple of years after you passed. The poor thing went from zero kids to two kids over the course of a registry office wedding and a few finger sandwiches. I was young and I welcomed her with open arms. Despite becoming motherless when you passed, I have never felt motherless, and I’m thankful for that.)
"They say you left a gap.
Over the years, therapists tried to get me talking about the massive gap you’d left in my life, but I couldn’t tap into it. For a while, I didn’t believe them. I truly thought they were looking for something that simply wasn’t there. Then I had Anna."
(As I reflected on the bond she and I shared by the time she was three years old, I thought about you a lot. About the bond you and I must have shared and about the gap you must have left, even though I could never quite put my finger on it. Mostly, though, I thought about how hard it must have been for you to know that you were going to leave me. Leave us.)
Question:
What exactly does "something" mean here? I know it's something related to the gap. But what exactly does it refer to? i just don't understand why the author's saying she could never understand it even after having Anna, let alone before having her.

I’m closing this question as off-topic, per community consensus on the other similar questions asked here about meanings of other words/phrases from the same blog post. This question has already been asked on ELL where it's received several answers. The consensus here seems to be that there's a lot of doubt over whether such a blog post actually constitutes "literature".

As with my answer to meaning of "tap into it", I think that the "something" referenced is the "massive gap" that the therapists are trying to have her explore, namely the death of her mother. Her father feels an extreme sense of loss from the death of her mother. She, having been too young to really have formative memories of her mother, never really felt a sense of loss from the death. It's hard to mourn someone that you don't really remember knowing. Now, having had her own child, she's realized how much those first few years probably meant, even if she can't remember them.
